# Apply data- element to Datatables cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-data

I am trying to make the cells of a specific column all have a `data-ip` attribute associated with them so that I can later read it with jQuery when I need the data. I could create a separate column that is hidden that contains the `ip` however I would like to attempt this method first.

I am trying to associate a more readable `hostname` column with an `ip`. Here is the column from `aoColumns`:

```
{"sTitle": "Hostname", sName: "host", sWidth: "30%", sClass: 'host', mData:
    function (source) {
        return source.hostname
    }
}
```

As you see in the code I have `source.hostname` which fills the `td` with the JSON `hostname` however I want to apply a `data-ip` attribute that contains the `source.ip` data. Is this possible?

Edit - whole jQuery element:

```
$('#servicesTable').dataTable({
    'aaData': servicesJson['registered_services'],
    'aoColumns': [
        {"sTitle": "Hostname", sName: "host", sWidth: "30%", sClass: 'host', mData:
            function (source) {
                return source.hostname
            }
        },
        {"sTitle": "Service", sName: "service", sWidth: "30%", sClass: 'service', mData: "serviceName"},
        {"sTitle": "Monitored?", sName: "monitored", sWidth: "10%", sClass: 'monitored', mData:
            function (source) {
                if (typeof source.active === 'undefined')
                    return '';
                var monitor = source.active;
                if (monitor == 1)
                    return "<input type='checkbox' class='monitor' name='monitored' checked />";
                else
                    return "<input type='checkbox' class='monitor' name='monitored'/>";
            }
        },
        {"sTitle": "Status", sName: "status", sWidth: "15%", sClass: 'status', mData: "status"},
        {"sTitle": "URL", sName: "url", sWidth: "5%", sClass: 'url right', mData:
            function (source) {
                if (typeof source.url === 'undefined' || source.url == '')
                    return '';
                return "<a class='ui-icon ui-icon-link' href='" + source.url + "'>NAGIOS</a>";
            }
        },
        {"sTitle": "Add/Remove", sName: "add-remove-new", sWidth: "15%", sClass: 'add-remove-new', mData:
            function (source, type, val) {
                if (typeof source.addRemove === 'undefined')
                    return "<button class='add-remove-new' type='button'>Remove</button>";
                else
                    return "<button class='add-remove-new' type='button'>Add</button>";
            }
        },
    ],
    'bJQueryUI': true,
    'bInfo': false,
    'bPaginate': false,
    'bSort': false,
    'bFilter': true,
    'iDisplayLength': 25,
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        //function that is called everytime an element is added or a redraw is called
        //aData[] is an arraw of the values stored in datatables for the row
        //to change a row's html use $('td:eq('+index+')', nRow).html( html here ); where index is the index of the td element in the row
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is. Use jQuery's `.data()` to set the `td`'s `data-ip`, as follows:

```
$('#my-td').data('ip', source.ip);
```

More information [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-obj).

**Update:** after you provided more detailes about your code, I did a lot of reading on the DataTables plugin and it really does seem to be a struggle to do this kind of manipulation via API directly. I would suggest you to follow your own idea of a hidden extra column, or to do as follows:

```
return source.hostname+'<span class="id-info">'+source.ip+'</span>';
```

The `span` would be hidden of course, and then your page would have some jQuery to pick this information after the table is created and give it to the `td` as its `data-ip`.

Not much of a difference when it comes to code ugliness, but at least it wouldn't leave a hidden column on the page since your jQuery could remove the `span` after adding the IP to the `data-ip` attribute.

Comment: I understand how to set the `data` element, however the selector part is the problem. What would the selector be for this? I don't really have any kind of id to use. I have no idea what would be the selector here.

Comment: I see. Guess I'll need a larger part of the code to help with this. In which context is the piece of code that you provided being called?

Comment: I have added more context.